# Does anyone have documentation for MDM Zinc 4.0's Joystick API?

Tags: flash, mdm-zinc

I'm trying to figure out how to use MDM Zinc 4.0's Joystick API and there are no LiveDocs on this since the software is no longer supported.

Any help (especially documentation for Zinc) would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Here a Copy of All LiveDocs Archives of Zinc 4.0 - Script 4.0 API, Help Files and Command SDK -:

http://depositfiles.com/files/47ag9bp1g

Not are orderd and fault organize the Links, but how in Little Time is Possible Dissapear, here are the total htmls in:

http://www.multidmedia.com/support/livedocs/zinc/4.0/

A pity that excellent software like Flash and Zinc, these Yankees - dirty game - wanted to eliminate because are too good ...

I hope someone will be useful ... I not understand why zinc have not made a chm help well ... I do not understand ...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try any code? If you're coding an AS3 project (you tagged Flash) then maybe you can check **[Google results](https://www.google.com/#q=as3+joystick+API)** for articles like **[this post](http://johnstejskal.com/wp/virtual-joystick-for-mobile-games-using-as3/)**. Also useful is the **[manual](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/GameInput.html)** page.

I don't use MDM Zinc but out of interest, I looked into it for you...

AS3 code should be enough. Search for Flash joystick tutorials. Maybe that's why Zinc doesn't need to document it? (ie: just read the Flash **[manual](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/GameInput.html)** instead).

According to **[this CodeIdol page](http://codeidol.com/community/flash/using-zinc/14195/)** (too bad, broken image links)...

> When launching Zinc for the first time, you get a pop-up window asking
>   what type of application you want to create...
>
> You can control a variety of Zinc settings...

So you should see something like below whereby in that **Input Devices** tab you setup **Joystick**. The screenshot is from version **2.5** so if Joystick is not a tab in your version (**4.0**) then maybe it's a now-removed feature. Otherwise maybe the options there will give you a hint on how to use it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The first article is about a virtual joystick on a Flash movie rather than using an API that uses a real controller. The second uses Adobe AIR, which I'm avoiding but may reconsider.

Comment: I'll check to see if 4.0 has something about joysticks on it, but I didn't see it the first time.